# How to select column comments in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to select the column comments of a table. What table has this information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no SQL standard compliant support for comments in SQL Server.

The only thing that comes close to the usual `comment on ...` syntax is using an extended property to store the comments.

To list the values of an extended property, you can use the following statement:

```
SELECT objname, cast(value as varchar) as value 
FROM fn_listextendedproperty ('MS_DESCRIPTION','schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'your_table', 'column', null);
```

This assumes you are using property named `MS_DESCRIPTION` to store the comments.

To set a comment using an extended property you have to use the `sp_addextendedproperty()` function.

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to select all auto increment columns?

Comment: Should be somewhere in `syscolumns`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260398%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx Just hunt through the system tables

Comment: Identity Column `SELECT  * FROM syscolumns where (status & 128) <> 0`

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   sys.extended_properties
WHERE
   major_id = OBJECT_ID('mytable')
   AND
   minor_id = COLUMNPROPERTY(major_id, 'MyColumn', 'ColumnId')
```